# DataFrame detect when one column becomes bigger than another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am wondering about code that detect when values in one column BECOME bigger than values in another column. So in the example below in row index 1 B becomes bigger than A and in row index 3 A becomes bigger than B. I would like to get a DataFrame that highlights row 1 and 2 and also which column that became bigger than which.

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
   A  B
0  3  2
1  5  6
2  3  7
3  8  2
```

Desired result:

```
In [1]: df_result
Out[1]: 
   RES
0  0
1  -1
2  0
3  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check where `A` is greater than `B` cast to `int8` with [`view`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) and take the [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df.A.gt(df.B).view('i1').diff().fillna(0, downcast = 'i1')

0    0
1   -1
2    0
3    1
dtype: int8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.sign` with a column difference to know sign of the difference and then replace values with column label:

```
df['who_is_bigger'] = (pd.DataFrame(np.sign(df['col1'] - df['col2']))
.replace({-1: 'col2', 1: 'col1', 0:'same_size'}))
```

will return in `who_is_bigger` column the column label of the biggest column and same_size string if the two columns have same value

Answer (score 0):

If the comparison is specifically between two columns, you can take the difference between both, let's say we've got this dataframe:

```py
>>> data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'b': [5, 3, 4, 1, 2]})
>>> data
   a  b
0  5  5
1  4  3
2  3  4
3  2  1
4  1  2
```

Then by doing `data['a'] - data['b']` we get the deltas between each, just like this:

```py
>>> data['a'] - data['b']
0    0
1    1
2   -1
3    1
4   -1
```

Where `0` means that both columns in that row possess the same number, a number higher than `0` means that the left column (`a`) is greater than the right column (`b`) and a negative number, the opposite.